# Google Calendar API v3 .Net Service

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api

I have what I consider to be a simple requirement of Google Calendars but for the life of me I cannot find anything online to help me achieve it.

All I want to do is show on a web page one of my calendars from my Google Account (not the end users) and then allow them to create events/bookings. Not sure this can be done but seems quite a simple feature to me.

From my reading online it looks like I need to not use Oauth2 but to create a Calendar Service and connect that way. This is the code that I currently have which creates the service fine without complaints but i have no idea how to render a calendar from this and can't seem to find any decent examples anywhere.

```
private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "DetailsRemoved";
private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = @"DetailsRemoved";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalendarService x = BuildService();
    //Render the Calendar somehow
}

/// <summary>
/// Build a Calendar service object authorized with the service account.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Calendar service object.</returns>
static CalendarService BuildService()
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate =
        new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH),
                             "notasecret",
                             X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
    {
        ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        Scope = CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue(),
    };
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        Authenticator = auth
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks